# How to render HABTM association?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Rails n00b here...

I have a *has_and_belongs_to_many* association between a post and category model. I'm trying to render the categories for each post like so:

```
<%= post.Categories.each do |category| %>
<div id="categories_home">
    <ul>
        <li><%= category.description %></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm getting an error; I haven't been able to find an example how to properly render these types of relationships.

Should I be using a has_and_belongs_to_many :through association instead and implement a response action to get all records for the CategoriesPosts table and then iterate through the table using the post_id?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if the problem persists please include models as well as error messages in your post and make sure you ran your migrations

Answer (score 0):

You should invoke the lowercase getter method on post. also post should normally be an instance variable and therefore @post.

```
<%= @post.categories.each do |category| %>
<div id="categories_home">
    <ul>
        <li><%= category.description %></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

By convention, only class names and constants start with a capital letter in Ruby.

Your association seems fine so far.